# Rails json API with Rspec -> ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

So I have an api under

```
#controllers/api/v4/...rb
```

this api render jbuilder json under:

```
#views/api/v4/....json.jbuilder
```

I have spec:

```
#spec/controllers/api/v4/..._spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V4::AlbumsController do

  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in(user)
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "returns correct types" do
      get :index, {:format => :json, :user_id => user.id}
      puts @request.body
      puts response.body
      user_response = json_response
      puts user_response
    end
  end
end
```

Everything is right until rendering when I get this:

```
Failure/Error: get :index, {:format => :json, :user_id => user.id}
  ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template api/v4/albums/index, api/api/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
     * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007ff4721d9f20>"
```

Does someone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: are you supporting both html & json responses?

Comment: My apis are in their own folder api and I set the default render to json in the routes.rb ->  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include jbuilder in my gemfile... so it can render the .json.jbuilder views.